# How to find the top 10 performing values of each week in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I would like to return the top 10 performing (by average) variables for each week in my DataFrame. It is about 2 years worth of data

I am using Python to figure this out but, would also eventually like to do it in SQL.

I have been able to produce code that returns the top 10 for the latest week but, would like results for every week

- Creating df that creates the datetime range

```py
range_max = rtbinds['pricedate'].max()
range_min = range_max - datetime.timedelta(days=7)

sliced_df = rtbinds[(rtbinds['pricedate'] >= range_min) 
                    & (rtbinds['pricedate'] <= range_max)]
```

- grouping by 'shadow'

```py
sliced_df.groupby(['pricedate','cons_name']).aggregate(np.mean)
         .sort_values('shadow').head(10)
```

- returns for the first week of data.

```
    pricedate   cons_name       shadow
    2019-04-26  TEMP71_24753    -643.691
    2019-04-27  TMP175_24736    -508.062
    2019-04-25  TMP109_22593    -383.263
    2019-04-23  TEMP48_24759    -376.967
    2019-04-29  TEMP71_24753    -356.476
                TMP175_24736    -327.230
                TMP273_23483    -303.234
    2019-04-27  TEMP71_24753    -294.377
    2019-04-28  TMP175_24736    -272.603
                TMP109_22593    -270.887
```

But, I would like a list that returns the top 10 for each week until the earliest date of my data

Comment: Please, could you provide an example of `rtbinds` and check if I edited the script properly?

Comment: Hello, sorry rtbinds is the name of the dataframe with cols [pricedate, cons_name, shadow]

Comment: Do you want the mean of shadow per day or per week? You have it per day at the moment.

Comment: I would like the top 10 "cons_name" by there average over a week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heads up `pd.sort_values` is sorting by default in ascending order, so when you take `head(10)`, it's actually the worst 10 if we consider the natural ordering of real numbers.

Now for your problem, here is a solution

First we need to create some columns to identify the week of the year (rtbins is renamed df):

```
df['year'] = df['pricedate'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
df['week'] = df['pricedate'].apply(lambda x: x.isocalendar()[1])
```

Then we will group the data by `['year', 'week', 'cons_name']` :

```
df2 = df.groupby(['year', 'week', 'cons_name'], as_index=False).aggregate(np.mean)
```

You should get now a dataframe where for each (year, week) you have only one record of a cons_name with the mean shadow.

Then we will take the top 10 for each (year, week)

```
def udf(df):
    return df.sort_values('shadow').head(10)

df2.groupby(['year', 'week'], as_index=False).apply(udf)
```

This should give you the result you want.

Comment: Thanks Ismail! This worked. and the higher negative value means i is a higher preformer

Comment: Ismail, there was a bit of a change to this. I actually need the new dataframe to have the top 10 values from the last 7 days for EVERYDAY.

So, the top 10 from the past week from 5/17/2019 then the top 10 from the past week from 5/16/2019

Is that something you can help with?

Comment: Would a function where you enter a date and it returns the top 10 from the past week work for you ? If yes then I suggest you create a function: `def top10_from_past_week(df, date):` and inside the function you filter your df just like you did with sliced_df in your initial post and return a df or a list of top 10 cons_name for the (date - 7 days --> date). If you actually need a dataframe where each line has a date and the top10 from the past 7 days from that days, it's possible do it by hand using a loop and this previous function. Let me know what you actually need and I ll try it out.

Comment: Hi Ismail, I think two functions where you enter the date and it returns the top 10 from that week would work and one where a new dataframe is actually created would work too.  My Python is a bit rusty so I need the extra nudge! I appreciate the help